Ubuntu Server 24.04 black screen during installation
I'm able to select the bootable drive, then "Try or install Ubuntu Server", then it begins installing. Everything seems good without any errors until it suddenly black screens. last frame of the screen before it goes black:

I'm Running an X670E GAMING PLUS Board with a 7950x on integrated graphics. I've successfully installed Mint without any issue and tried multiple Ubuntu Server downloads which have all black screened at the same place. When black screened the monitor wont show it's built in interface unless the HDMI is unplugged. Keyboard stays lit up.

The display output switched over to the display port, so I swapped the HDMI out for a DisplayPort cable and that solved my issue.

I saw the same behavior with a Gigbyte A520i motherboard.  Thank you for posting your answer, it saved me a bunch of headaches.
